# C# secondary sort with lambda expression

Tags: c#

How to sort a list in C# with secondary sorting.
For example if I have a class called Student with two fields FirstName and LastName.
Until now I've sorted the list as follows:

```
MyStudents.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.LastName.CompareTo(s2.LastName));
```

I wanted to know how can I sort the list first by last name and then by first name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`Sort` doesn't have that capability.

Linq can do this simply:

```
MyStudents.OrderBy(s => s.LastName).ThenBy(s => s.FirstName)
```

Ensure you are using at least .NET 3.5 and have the `System.Linq` namespace referenced.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
MyStudents.OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ThenBy(e => e.FirstName);
```

Comment: you have a typo - `ThenBy` not `ThanBy`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx)

```
var sortedList = MyStudents.OrderBy(s => s.LastName).ThenBy(s=> s.FirstName);
```

note that `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` does not change the order of `MyStudents` list and they return an `IEnumerable<Student>`, so if you need a `List<Student>` use [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb342261%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).